# How do I disable syntax checking in LDAP?

Tags: ldap, openldap

A colleague of mine is trying to disable syntax checking in LDAP. We tried searching Google on how to do this, but couldn't find any help.

So..
How do I disable syntax checking in LDAP by using LDIF ? What command should i use?

Thanks for the help guys

Comment: He is trying it why? What's the problem with using LDAP as it is already defined?

Comment: Disable syntax checking on what? If it is to disable the syntax check on for example phone number attribute, just create an auxiliary schema with an attribute `telephoneNumber2` which has not the telephoneNumber syntax but the directory string syntax.

Comment: It's for testing purposes, and since syntax checking creates quite some overhead, I want to(temporarily) disable it

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge there is no way of disabling completly the syntax checking in the configuration of OpenLDAP.

You can still download the source, modify it and recompile OpenLDAP.

You could also use another LDAP Directory. For example, it seems Red Hat Directory Server has a configuration to disable the syntax checking.